# Objective-C / Cocos2D Repeating Code Reduction

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, reduction

Anyone know how I would be able to reduce my following lines of code?  I'm still fairly new at objective-c / cocos2D and my following codes look like train wrecks.  If it were PHP, I can just create a loop easily to get all these in, but I'm just not familiar enough with obj-c yet to figure it out.

```
    dinosaur1_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur1-c.png"];
    dinosaur2_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur2-c.png"];
    dinosaur3_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur3-c.png"];
    dinosaur4_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur4-c.png"];
    dinosaur5_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur5-c.png"];
    dinosaur6_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur6-c.png"];
    dinosaur7_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur7-c.png"];
    dinosaur8_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur8-c.png"];
    dinosaur9_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur9-c.png"];
    dinosaur10_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur10-c.png"];
    dinosaur11_c = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"dinosaur11-c.png"];

    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur1_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur2_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur3_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur4_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur5_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur6_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur7_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur8_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur9_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur10_c];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dinosaur11_c];
```

Any inputs are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are `dinosaur1_c` your instance variables, or are they temporaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend managing these objects with an `NSMutableArray`, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *sprites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 1; i <= 11; i++) {
    id dino = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dinosaur%d-c.png",i]];
    [sprites addObject:dino];
    [sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:dino];
}

// Since I don't know what your addChild: method does, the 'sprites' array exists to let you access the objects later, outside of the 'for' loop if desired...
// So where you would've used dinosaur4_c before, you would instead use [sprites objectAtIndex:4]
// This also demonstrates how to cast the return value from -objectAtIndex: to a CCSprite *
CCSprite *certainDino = (CCSprite *)[sprites objectAtIndex:4];

// Then, when done working with the sprites
[sprites release];
```

Comment: Why not just use a C-Array (or CCArray)? It's faster than a linked list.

Comment: You never add anything to 'sprites'

Comment: Thanks for the input bneely.  I probably should have mentioned that the dinosaur1_c's are instance variables.  However I'm still not quite sure what is going on with the Dino *dino part of the loop.  What type of instance variable is *dino supposed to be from?

Comment: I've never used cocos2d so that was a guess. I did a quick google search and found a reference to the CCSprite interface that defines the return type of +spriteWithSpriteFrameName: as `id` so I'll edit my answer to use that. As for the instance variables, I assume they're being used elsewhere as well? That was what the NSMutableArray accomplished; providing another way to create these objects and reference them later without needing one line of code per object.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me bneely.

However, I'm getting this error:
[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]

Plus I may have a little bit of a problem with the id's because I need to use the position.x and position.y's of the dino's in another method (not listed here), but xcode says I cannot use id's for positions.  Sorry I didn't know that I would have an issue with position and id's.

Comment: To use them as objects, you can cast them. Example: `(CCSprite*)[sprites objectAtIndex:4]` . And yes, you need to know what the array size is and not ask for an object beyond the array bounds. To do this: `int arraySize = [sprites count];` . Valid objects will be in the range 0...arraySize-1 (NSArray uses a zero-based index).

Comment: If you need further help, such as regarding using NSArray, it would be worthwhile to start a new stackoverflow question.

Comment: Yea it seems that way. Thank you very much for taking the time for me!  I'll check your answer as the solution since others seem to agree with it. :D